# Does anyone recognize this plant?

Tags: identification

I just acquired a new plant, but the guy I bought it from had no idea about its name. So can you help me out? [image][image]

Comment: More photos please, one close up and one further away - these two are out of focus

Comment: You say that this is a new plant you've acquired but it looks quite old to include a few weeds and has been pruned?

Comment: stormy yes the plant looks old but it was cheap :) and it growing new shoots at the base ,had no idea that caps mean't yelling anyhow got the point ,

Comment: I understand quite well...honest.  grins!

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of Mirabilis jalapa.
It has trumpet flowers, which can arrive in a variety of different colors.
It grows voraciously from a large tuber in the ground, with a similar look to a yam. 
In my yard it is an obnoxious weed that spreads easily via it's seeds and is difficult to eradicate.

Comment: yes Mirabilis jalapa is a tough weed , as i only have containers no worries , thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Lindernia dubia, Yellow-seeded False Pimpernel. What type and color of flowers?  Having technical problems....

Comment: thank you stormy, it has not flowered yet ,leaves look shriveled , and light green the stems are reddish